# Building a Data Scraping Tool for County GIS/Tax Databases

Tags: database, web-scraping

Is it possible to build a tool that scrapes data from County GIS/Tax Databases? Basically, if I say I want several common fields (Parcel #, Assessed Value, Acreage, Owner Name, Owner Address, etc.) for EVERY PARCEL in a county.

Typically I run a macro that searches the database for every parcel I have in a list but it's time consuming and getting the list of parcels in the county can be a pain in the a**. I want to know if there's a way I can just yank the data out of the database that the county website pulls from.

Comment: When you say the "database" do you mean the actual relational database where the data is stored or a website you can search. This would obviously totally depend on the county and what they had decided to make public and how.

Comment: You need to give us more information - database? where is it located? any example where you can reach it or post queries to it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you talk about the database which is a repository of the data and you cannot access the website database publicly. All the database servers are running in the on-premises environment.

If you need the county data, you can use automated tools or hire a developer that can give the required data in the file or whatever format you want.